# how to use slicing to get 2 numbers in a multiple array (numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

if i have an array

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

output would be a =[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]

using slice [start:endindex:stepindex],
how could i retrieve 3 and 7?

is it possible?

I have tried

```
a[:3:2]
```

this gave me 1rst row and third row

Answer (score 1):

```
In [928]: a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])                                                      
In [929]: a                                                                                            
Out[929]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

[3,7] isn't regular pattern in this 2d array.  But its flattened view:

```
In [931]: a.ravel()                                                                                    
Out[931]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
In [932]: a.ravel()[2::4]                                                                              
Out[932]: array([3, 7])
In [933]: a.flat[2::4]                                                                                 
Out[933]: array([3, 7])
```

Now guarantee that it can be extended for larger arrays and selections.